# Is there a way to port an Eclipse project settings to CMake?

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm currently looking to migrate off Eclipse at work to manage projects -- we use a variety of projects with common configurations, which becomes difficult to upkeep among all the different projects. I think using a program like CMake or similar would be beneficial, but I'm struggling to find a seamless way to migrate over from Eclipse over to CMake.

Is there a way to easily port configurations from a Eclipse project (.project and .cproject files) to a CMake file or configuration? This would help speed up development tremendously.